# Ionic iOS Audio Track Error (.mp3 Not Found)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic Application for both Android and iOS.
I'm using the Ionic Audio plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-audio) and its working find on Android.

However when i tested the application on iOS i got an error that it can not locate the .mp3 file:
[image]

My .mp3 file is located in "assets/audio/" and the default link i use and which works perfectly on Android is: "assets/audio/portuguese.mp3".

I tried the same on iOS but it did not work. I tried several path and failed *(one of them is in the attached picture)*. then i tried getting it online through "http://www.xxxxxx.com/portuguese.mp3" and it worked on iOS! so i figured out that it must be the path that is going wrong.

Appreciate any help in locating the right/correct path in order to retrieve the audio .mp3 on iOS.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding cordova-plugin-file https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file to the project fixed it!